# How to setup transitive Many-to-One relations in Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

I met a problem while setting up Hibernate for my model. Below you can see the part of DB which causes the difficulty. PKs are marked in red, all given relations are Many-to-One. I thought of adding `airline_id` and `connection_id` directly into `Flight` table but this may cause a situation when `Flight` will contain invalid data (`airline_id` and `connection_id` pair for which there's no record in `AirlineConnection`).

I would like to store `Airline` and `Connection` as fields of `class Flight` but I'm confused with the technical part. As far as I understand, `AirlineConnection` is a join table for relations `Flight` :  `Connection` and `Flight` : `Airline` but `@JoinTable` annotation requires from join table to store references for both tables it joins (correct me if I'm wrong).
So my question is "is it possible to store `Airline` and `Connection` in `Flight` without adding `airline_id` and `connection_id` fields into DB table `Flight` and why if not?"

Thanks in advance!

[image: DB Scheme]

Comment: No. You should model AirlineConnection as an entity.

Comment: @JBNizet Nizet Actually, that's what I've done but hoped there's some other solution. Thank you anyway.